# Name all combinations of two uneven lists

Tags: r, nested-lists, purrr

How can I create all combinations of two uneven lists *and* map names onto the result? I have used the purrr package's [`cross2` function](http://www.inside-r.org/node/382732) to produce the combinations, but I can't figure out an elegant way to name the resulting list by combining the names from the original lists.

```r
a <- list(
  "alpha" = c(1, 2, 3),
  "beta" = c(4, 5, 6),
  "gamma" = c(7, 8, 9)
)

b <- list(
  "charlie" = c("a", "b"),
  "foxtrot" = c("x", "y")
)

library(purrr)

cross2(a, b)
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [[4]][[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[4]][[2]]
#> [1] "x" "y"
#> 
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [[5]][[1]]
#> [1] 4 5 6
#> 
#> [[5]][[2]]
#> [1] "x" "y"
#> 
#> 
#> [[6]]
#> [[6]][[1]]
#> [1] 7 8 9
#> 
#> [[6]][[2]]
#> [1] "x" "y"
```

I'd like to keep this same list structure, but map names onto both levels of the list like so:

```r
list(
  "alpha.charlie" = list(
    "a" = c(1, 2, 3),
    "b" = c("a", "b")),
  "alpha.foxtrot" = list(
    "a" = c(1, 2, 3),
    "b" = c("x", "y"))
  # ETC
)
#> $alpha.charlie
#> $alpha.charlie$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $alpha.charlie$b
#> [1] "a" "b"
#> 
#> 
#> $alpha.foxtrot
#> $alpha.foxtrot$a
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> $alpha.foxtrot$b
#> [1] "x" "y"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use `setNames` (or `set_names`) after the fact.

There is a simple example in the documentation for `cross2`, naming the elements within each list with `map` and `setNames`.  In your case, that would look like

```
cross2(a, b) %>% 
    map(setNames, c("a", "b"))

[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1 2 3

[[1]]$b
[1] "a" "b"


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 4 5 6

[[2]]$b
[1] "a" "b"
...
```

You'd then need to name the higher level lists, which can be done by creating the names you want from the original names of lists `a` and `b`.  I took the `levels` of the `interaction` of the names to create the names.  Depending on your real situation, this may not scale well.

```
cross2(a, b) %>% 
    map(setNames, c("a", "b")) %>% 
    setNames(levels(interaction(names(a), names(b))))

$alpha.charlie
$alpha.charlie$a
[1] 1 2 3

$alpha.charlie$b
[1] "a" "b"


$beta.charlie
$beta.charlie$a
[1] 4 5 6

$beta.charlie$b
[1] "a" "b"
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This nested `lapply` gets names on the higher level:

```
myList <- unlist(lapply(a, function(i) lapply(b, function(j) list(i, j))), recursive = F)

myList
$alpha.charlie
$alpha.charlie[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$alpha.charlie[[2]]
[1] "a" "b"


$alpha.foxtrot
$alpha.foxtrot[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

$alpha.foxtrot[[2]]
[1] "x" "y"

...
```

You can add the second level of names with a second `lapply`:

```
myList <- lapply(myList, function(i) {names(i) <- c("a", "b"); i})

myList
$alpha.charlie
$alpha.charlie$a
[1] 1 2 3

$alpha.charlie$b
[1] "a" "b"


$alpha.foxtrot
$alpha.foxtrot$a
[1] 1 2 3

$alpha.foxtrot$b
[1] "x" "y"

...
```